# 502 bad gateway openresty error in kubernetes due to ingress issue

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, argocd

I'm running k3s in the 3 VM with one master node and 3 worker node. The IPs of the following VM are:

```
master node:  10.19.119.2
worker1 node: 10.19.119.3
worker2 node: 10.19.119.4
worker3 node: 10.19.119.5
```

At the endpoint, we are using nginx proxy manager to route the traffic and to access the cluster, we opened the 10.19.119.3:443.

I have few question regarding this situation.

1. Do we still need ingress controller in the k3s cluster?
2. When i write the ingress, Automatically, the status.Loadbalacer.ingress filed is filled with the worker ndoes IPs. How ?

Another scenario regarding this setup
In nginx proxy manager, we set the domain with the cluster endpoint, Then we map it in /etc/hosts to access with that domain. When i write ingress and route it, Its getting 502 bad gateway error (openresty). I dont understand whats the issue because im still confused regarding the top question. I have also install nginx ingress controller but not working.

Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    # If you encounter a redirect loop or are getting a 307 response code
    # then you need to force the nginx ingress to connect to the backend using HTTPS.
    #
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: testargocd.fonepay.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              name: https
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - argocd.safefamilyapp.com`
    secretName: argocd-secret # do not change, this is provided by Argo CD
```

The service is working fine (argocd-server) as i checked it with port-forwarding to the service. I dont get what is wrong.

K3s version: v1.20.7+k3s1

Thanks in advance

Note: Everything was working properly but when we remove the default traefik ingress controller from k3s

I tried to install the nginx ingress controller.
I checked the service through port forwarding and it was working fine.